# Large sets not containing arithmetic progressions of length 3 in intervals

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, co.combinatorics, asymptotics, arithmetic-progression

Given a large enough natural number $N$, let $\Delta_N=\{A \subseteq [N, 2N]: A$ contains no arithmetic progressions of length $3 \},$ where for natural numbers $N<M$ we have $[N, M]=\{N, N+1, ..., M\}.$ Also let:

$a_N=Max\{|A|/N: A\in \Delta_N     \}.$

$\delta_N=Max\{ \Sigma_{n\in A}1/n: A\in \Delta_N    \}.$

**Question 1.** What are $a_N$ and $\delta_N?$

**Question 2.** What are $\liminf_N a_N$ and $\limsup_N a_N$?

**Question 3** What are $\liminf_N \delta_N$ and $\limsup_N \delta_N$?

---

The following questions might be easier:

**Question 4.** Is $\liminf_N \delta_N >0$? What about $\limsup_N \delta_N$?

**Question 5.** Is $\liminf_N a_N >0$? What about $\limsup_N a_N$?

> Prof. Tao's suggestion says that asymptotically we have $\delta_N \thicksim  a_N log2$, and so it suffices to answer one of the above questions to know the answer of the other one.

Comment: sn't question 3 already covered by Roth's theorem?  For any $\epsilon$,
there exists $N_0(\epsilon)$ such that once $N \geq N_0(\epsilon)$
every subset of $[0,N]$ of size $\geq \epsilon N$ contains an arithmetic
progression of length $3$.  Hence $a_N < \epsilon$ and $\delta_N < \epsilon$
once $N \geq N_0(\epsilon)$, which means that $a_N \rightarrow 0$ 
and $\delta_N \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: An exact answer to Questions 1 and 2 is not expected once $N$ is at all large;
even the rate of asymptotic decay is not known, though there's an explicit
construction (Behrend 1946) showing that the decay is no faster than
$\exp(-c (\log N)^{1/2})$ for some absolute constant $c>0$.

Comment: We may restrict our attention to $\ A\ $ such that $\ N\in A$.

Comment: I see that $\ \sum\frac 1n\ $ makes sense. And still, it is somewhat arbitrary. Is there a special extra reason for it?

Comment: A moderately instant observation: Let $\ N:=1+3+\ldots+3^{t-1}=\frac{3^t-1}2.\ $ Then a set $\ T\ $ of $\ |T|=2^t\ $ integers $\ \sum_{k=0}^{t-1}b_k\cdot 3^k\ $ (where $\ b_k=0\ or\ 2)\ $ will not contain any 3-term arithmetic progression. Here $\ T\subseteq\{0\ldots N\}.\ $ Thus $\ a_N,\ $ from the ***Question*** (general $\ N)\ $ is of the magnitude $\ N^{\frac{\log(2)}{\log(3)}}\ $ or higher.

Comment: Above $\ N\ $ should be replaced by twice as large, i.e. by $\ N:=3^t-1.\ $ Otherwise everything is fine.

Comment: The results of Croot in http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2384737 should give enough stability of $a_N$ and $\delta_N$ to conclude asymptotically that $\delta_N \sim a_N \log 2$, I think.

Comment: A relevant paper for question 1 is http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.3057 .